# Function in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, but not in $L^1(\mathbb{R^3})$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, function-spaces

What is an example of a function that is in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ but not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

I don't really know how to approach this question. I know there is this result that says that the function $f:B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is weakly differentiable if and only if $\alpha>1-n$. I was thinking that maybe there is a similar way to construct an example for this problem, but I have no idea.

Comment: Food for thought: the behavior near the origin isn't too important, so you may as well consider $C^{\infty}$ functions. In $\Bbb{R}$, consider a smooth function $f$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{0.6}}$ for large $|x|$ (and use a smooth bump function to define it however you like near the origin). So, you have a $C^{\infty}$ function. This is certainly not in $L^1$, but it is in $L^2$, also for large $|x|$, we have $f'(x)\sim\frac{1}{|x|^{1.6}}$ which is in $L^2$, so $f\in W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R})\setminus L^1(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: If you want to be more precise with formulas, consider $f(x)=\phi(x)+[1-\phi(x)]\frac{1}{|x|^a}$, where $\phi$ is a smooth compactly supported function, which is identically $1$ in an open neighborhood of the origin. Then, $f$ is $C^{\infty}$, and $f\in W^{k,p}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ if and only if (since $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c$) the pointwise derivatives (which are the weak derivatives) of $\frac{1}{|x|^a}$, up to order $k$, lie in $L^p(B^c)$, where $B^c$ is the complement of the unit ball.

Comment: This is probably sufficient for an answer instead of a comment